# SQL Order By using concat

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, concatenation

I'm concatenating two fields and I only want to order by the second field (p.organizationname). Is that possible?

I'm displaying this field so I need a solution that doesn't include me having to select the fields separately.

Here is what i have so far:

```
SELECT distinct Concat(Concat(f.REFERENCEFILE, ','),p.ORGANIZATIONNAME)
FROM PEOPLE p,FOLDER f,FOLDERPEOPLE fp,folderinfo fi...
Order By concat(Concat(f.REFERENCEFILE, ','),p.ORGANIZATIONNAME)
```

Comment: You can just `ORDER BY p.ORGANIZATIONNAME`.

Comment: @a1ex07 Not when using `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: when i try that i get the "not a selected expression" error

Comment: Yeah, my bad - I missed `distinct` in the question...  I can't remove my comment though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` an aggregate instead of `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT Concat(Concat(f.REFERENCEFILE, ','),p.ORGANIZATIONNAME)
FROM PEOPLE p,FOLDER f,FOLDERPEOPLE fp,folderinfo fi...
GROUP BY Concat(Concat(f.REFERENCEFILE, ','),p.ORGANIZATIONNAME)
Order By MAX(p.ORGANIZATIONNAME)
```

The problem can be illustrated with an example:

```
ID Col1
1  Dog
1  Cat
2  Horse
```

Distinct ID? Easy: `1,2`

Distinct ID Order by Col1... wait.. which value of `Col1` should SQL use?  SQL is confused and angry.

Since you are using a concatenation of two fields and want to sort by one of those fields, you could also include the sort field in a `DISTINCT` subquery and then `ORDER BY` the sort field without including it in your `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a DISTINCT your ORDER BY clause should be specified in the SELECT, you can use a subquery to achieve the same result in your case since the Distinct values will be the same when you add P.ORGANIZATIONNAME

```
SELECT col 
  FROM( SELECT distinct Concat(Concat(f.REFERENCEFILE, ','),p.ORGANIZATIONNAME) a,
               p.ORGANIZATIONNAME b
          FROM PEOPLE p,FOLDER f,FOLDERPEOPLE fp,folderinfo fi... ) t
   order by b
```